# systemverilog - legal to pass '1 to module instantiation as port?

Tags: system-verilog

In SystemVerilog, is it legal to instantiate a module and pass '1 as the value on the port list? It appears that assignment patterns are disallowed according to the end of section 10.9. Are unsized bit literals allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's legal. And since a port connection is an assignment-like context (10.8), `'1` fills the width of the port with 1's.

And the rule you read in 10.9 has to do with port declarations, not port connections. A port expression would something like

```
module sub(input .p('{a,b,c}) ); // illegal to use assignment pattern here
```

Assignment patterns cannot be used in self-determined contexts.

Comment: So I can say: mod i_mod (.unp_arr({default: '{1, 2}})); As well as mod i_mod (.arr('1));? Assuming that's the appropriate pattern for the ports?

Comment: Yes, that’s how I understand what the LRM says.